# salesforce identify if current time in a timezone exists between a particular time range (only time not date)

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to identify if time for a timezone is within 7AM to 7PM.

But the problem below converts the time to another timezone.

```
Time myTime = Time.newInstance(dt.hour(), dt.minute(), dt.second(), dt.millisecond());
```

Heres the code I'm using:

```
List<User> users = [Select id, TimeZoneSidKey from User];
system.debug(users);

Set<String> uniqueTimeZones = new Set<String>();
for(User u : users)
{
    uniqueTimeZones.add(u.TimeZoneSidKey);
}

system.debug(uniqueTimeZones);
List<String> uniqueTimeZoneUnder7to7 = new List<String>();

datetime currentTime = datetime.now();


for(String s :uniqueTimeZones)
{
    if(s == 'Australia/Sydney')
    {
        Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone(s);

        DateTime dt = Datetime.now();
        dt =   dt.addSeconds((tz.getOffset(dt)/1000));

        //System.debug(string.valueOf(dt.to));

        //Integer myTimeHour = Integer.parse();

        Time myTime = Time.newInstance(dt.hour(), dt.minute(), dt.second(), dt.millisecond());
        Time lower = Time.newInstance(07, 00, 00, 000);
        Time upper = Time.newInstance(19, 00, 00, 000);


        System.debug(dt);
        System.debug(string.valueOf(dt));
        system.debug(dt.hour());
        System.debug(myTime);

        System.debug(lower);
        System.debug(upper);


        system.debug(myTime > lower);
        system.debug(myTime > lower);

        if(myTime > lower && myTime < upper)
        {
            system.debug('This timezone should be included ' + s);
        }
        else
        {
            system.debug('This timezone should not included ' + s);        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The output of `UserInfo.getTimeZone();`
 varies based on the user's time zone. This is an example output if the user’s time zone is America/Los_Angeles.  For this time zone, daylight saving time is -7 hours from GMT (-25200000 milliseconds) and standard time is -8 hours from GMT (-28800000 milliseconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates and Times don't have a timezone, whereas Datetime always does. Datetime values are actually stored, internally, in UTC and these values are automatically converted to the user's timezone in the Apex APIs. This can be troublesome when you want to check related Date or Time values in a given target timezone that is likely unrelated to the current user.

If you want to get the "time of day" from a Datetime in a given timezone, regardless of the User's timezone, the following is the best approach we have found:

```
public static Time getTimeInTimezone(Datetime normalizedDateTime, TimeZone targetTimezone) {
    // Unlike the Date object, the Time object does not have a valueOf method, so we have to - Convert to the
    // correct timezone in string format and parse through JSON.deserialize into the Time object.
    return (Time) JSON.deserialize('"' + normalizedDateTime.format('HH:mm:ss.sss', targetTimezone.getID()) + 'Z"',
            Time.class);
}
```

We have this as a utility class method.

If you use this instead of Time.newInstance (and you remove the other messing about with timezone offsets) you should get the results you are after:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(s);

    Datetime dt = Datetime.now();
    Time myTime = DateTimeUtils.getTimeInTimezone(dt, tz);
    Time lower = Time.newInstance(07, 00, 00, 000);
    Time upper = Time.newInstance(19, 00, 00, 000);

    if (myTime > lower && myTime < upper) {
        System.debug('This timezone should be included: ' + s);
    } else {
        System.debug('This timezone should not included: ' + s);        
    }
```